# I want to send a confirmation email when a user attempts to change their email address within my MVC3 application

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, email

. . . but I am not sure of the proper work-flow to make this happen.

I already send a confirmation email to the user's email address when they register - they are marked as 'inactive' until they click a link they receive in their email.

I want my users to be able to change their email when they please, and currently they can, but I would also like to be able to confirm the email address by having the user receive an email at their new email address with a link they have to click before the email change happens.

What is the proper work-flow to get this to happen?

Comment: You already described the workflow. What particular difficulties are you encountering into putting this workflow in action? Where are you stuck?

Comment: @DarinDimitrov When I am confirming a new account, the account data is stored in the db and simply set to 'inactive.' Where would I store the new email before it gets confirmed as the current email? Is it best to make another database entry somewhere that contains the new email to hold it until the address is confirmed? How long would I hold it there, how would I remove it if the user never confirmed it?